# make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile.inc'. Stop

Tags: linux, makefile, omnet++

I am trying to compile the program "OMNET++ 5.2" in Linux host, but whene I try to compilate my this one, I get this error :

```
Makefile:48: Makefile.inc: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile.inc'.  Stop.
```

Here is the link of tutorial that I had followed: 
http://vikashmainanwal.blogspot.com/2014/10/omnet-simulator-installation-steps-in.html

Can you please help me to avoid this probleme, so that I can start working on the practical part of my thesis.

Comment: This could mean that there is a line in your Makefile including the file named `Makefile.inc`, but this one is not found. Can you check to see if it's somewhere with the sources ?

Comment: omnetpp-5.2.1 : The file `Makefile.inc` is created with `./configure` (from Makefile.inc.in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tutorial is for an older version of OMNeT++, and it seems very low quality to me. Please follow the official Install Guide instead, [published on the website](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf) and included in the release archives as well (as a PDF file in the `doc` folder).

Comment: You may also need to install the `libqt5opengl5-dev` package in addition on some systems.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when attempting to install OMNET++ 5.6.1 today. I was attempting to install it onto Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

My issue was that I was following the *Linux* instructions on the [install guide](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf). But, **before** you do that (before you run `./configure` and `make`), the instructions in chapter 4.2 say:

> See the chapter specific to your Linux distribution for instructions on installing the packages needed by OMNeT++.

So I then went to chapter 5 and ran the *Ubuntu* instructions to install the prerequisite packages. After I installed the prerequisite packages, I was able to run `./configure` and `make` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

do not put OMNeT++ under **Program Files.**